# Creating relationships in CodeFirst EF which reference each other

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, relationships

I having some issues setting up the correct relationships that I require for a database.

In words...
I want to have a **Firm** which can multiple (zero:many) **Branch**

On the **Firm** I want to be able specify a **HeadOffice** which will exist will exist in the **Branch** table (zero:one)

What I expected to see is the **Firm** table to have the following fields: Id, Name, HeadOfficeId and on the **Branches** I expect to see: Id, TradingAs, Name, Firm_Id

Instead I see:

**Firm** table to have the following fields: Id, Name, HeadOfficeId

**Branches** I expect to see: Id, TradingAs, Name, Firm_Id, Firm_Id1

The model classes are as shown

```
public class Firm
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Branch> FirmBranches { get; set; }

    public virtual LawFirmBranch HeadOffice { get; set; }
}

public class Branch
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TradingAs {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}


    public Firm Firm { get; set; }

}
```

I understand that this causes a circular reference type issue and I am happy to have the Firm HeadOffice to initially to be Null until there are values in the FirmBranches property.

Is there some way that I can specify that the HeadOffice has the null or one type relationship

Comment: HeadOffice is already a 0 or 1 as it's either got an Id present or not....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to explicitly do this in your model, you can do this via data annotations:

public class Firm
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

```
public virtual ICollection<Branch> FirmBranches { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("HeadOffice")]
public int? FirmId {get;set;}

public virtual LawFirmBranch HeadOffice { get; set; }
```

}

If you dont want this exposed in your code, you'll need to do this via fluent:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Firm>()
            .HasOptional(f => f.HeadOffice)
            .WithOptionalDependent();
    }
```

This creates:

[image]

If you want to change the name of the key, you'd add a mapping to the end of the fluent map:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Firm>()
            .HasOptional(f => f.HeadOffice)
            .WithOptionalDependent()
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("YourKeyName"));
```